# Swift - best way to save an image to a server and retrive it

Tags: php, mysql, json, image, swift

Let's say i have an app which lets the user choose or take an image, input some data and after some validation the data should be sent to a server, which will have to be brought later on.

**The main part which i'm interested in is the image because that generated problems.**
I`ve tried sending the data through JSON but it didn`t work(i couldn`t encode the image in order to be able to retrive it in the same form).
The mysql db in which i'm trying to put the image data use a large blob type for that attribute.

What i really need is a solution/tutorial/advice/anything that would work in the latest XCODE version to upload/send/etc and image to a PHP server and retrive it from there.

Comment: Please provide the code which didnt worked.

Comment: If you use JSON, you'd want to have app base64 encode image (to render it in a text only format that could be included in JSON) and then the server side would presumably base64 decode it before storing it as a blob in the database. Alternatively, rather than JSON, you could create a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, in which you don't have to do any encoding/decoding of the image. You just have to pick which way you want to go. Both approaches have been discussed exhaustively here on Stack Overflow, which you'll probably find if you search for them.